# Android Studio - Can't run project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I want to create a Flutter project on Android Studio. I'm downloaded a Flutter and integrated to Android Studio. And when I want to run my project on my smartphone, I'm getting an error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Galaxy J5 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:526)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:524)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:523)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:265)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:372)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:212)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1208)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:189)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess Gradle is trying to download something, probably some libraries. Make sure you have a stable internet connection & Gradle offline mode is disabled.

Comment: How can I enable Gradle offline mode? Because I think my internet connection is really slow.

Comment: And how I can to download the neccessary packages and them include to Android Studio writing path?

Comment: 1. You should enable Gradle Offline only after all the dependencies are downloaded at least once. 2. You'll need a good internet connection for AS to download all the relevant and required dependencies.

Comment: can you type "flutter doctor -v" on the console and paste the logs here

Comment: is antivirus is ON on your system ?

Comment: No. I'm disabled antivirus.